# Eclipse 4 - Borderless window

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I'm trying to create a borderless window within my eclipse 4 application. Is it possible to do that with a tag in the e4xmi-model like

```
shellMaximized
```

or what is the best approach?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get this using a window using the `SWT.TOOL` style, probably `SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.TOOL`.

If you are defining the window in the Application.e4xmi you can specify the style using `styleOverride`. You do this on the 'persisted state' section of the 'Supplementary' tab of the page for the window in the Application.e4xmi.

Specify a key of `styleOverride` and a value of `1268` (which corresponds to `SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.TOOL`).

Unfortunately I can't test this here as I use a Mac which always has borderless windows!